# Basis for claim that the number of bugs per line of code is constant regardless of the language used

Tags: language-agnostic, code-metrics, lines-of-code

I've heard people say (although I can't recall who in particular) that the number of bugs per line of code is roughly constant regardless of what language is used. What is the research that backs this up?

**Edited to add**: I don't have access to it, but apparently the authors of [this paper](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/ICSEA.2009.41)
 "asked the question whether the number of bugs per lines of code (LOC) is the same for programs written in different programming languages or not."

Comment: Near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862277/what-is-the-industry-standard-for-bugs-per-1000-lines-of-code, closed as not a real question.

Comment: "What is the research that backs this up?"  I think this is defiantly a real question.  There is no opinion to listing credible sources

Comment: @Robert -- I hoped it was clear, but I am not asking for "the Industry Standard for bugs per 1000 Lines of Code", or anything like that. I am asking for references to research backing up this particular specific claim about bug density and language independence. I'm afraid I struggle to see how this would be a considered a duplicate.

Comment: I guess my point is that the other question was not taken seriously. The metric is essentially meaningless, in the same way that [Lines of Code Per Day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894099/10-lines-of-code-per-day-is-the-global-average-true) is meaningless. Just more fodder for the pointy-haired bosses to talk about.  I didn't vote to close, however.

Comment: "The metric is essentially meaningless" -- so it may be, but I'd be interested to see what was originally behind this claim all the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In his book [Code Complete](https://stevemcconnell.com/books/) (quoting from the 2nd Edition), in the chapter "Developer Testing," Steve McConnell cites a handful of studies across a variety of languages:

> - Industry average experience is about 1-25 errors per 1000 lines of code for delivered software. The software has usually been developed using a hodgepodge of techniques (Boehm 1981, Gremillion 1984, Yourdon 1989a, Jones 1998, Jones 2000, Weber 2003). Cases that have one-tenth as many errors as this are rare; cases that have 10 times more tend not to be reported. (They probably aren't ever completed!)
> - The Applications Division at Microsoft experiences about 10–20 defects per 1000 lines of code during in-house testing and 0.5 defects per 1000 lines of code in released product (Moore 1992). The technique used to achieve this level is a combination of the code-reading techniques described in Other Kinds of Collaborative Development Practices, and independent testing.
> - Harlan Mills pioneered "cleanroom development," a technique that has been able to achieve rates as low as 3 defects per 1000 lines of code during in-house testing and 0.1 defects per 1000 lines of code in released product (Cobb and Mills 1990).

These studies ranged from high-level languages like Java, down to C++ and C, all the way down to assembly. Considering the massive impact of Code Complete on software engineering as a discipline, I suspect it is responsible for popularizing this idea.

Comment: Thats all not very current data. With millions of open source projects out there and issue trackers one would assume it should be possible to better trace "defects".

Comment: @WolfgangFahl My answer is not an endorsement of the claim—just an attempt to trace how it entered the zeitgeist. 

Answer (score 8):

One possible source would be Les Hatton's 1995 paper "[Computer programming languages and safety-related systems](https://www.leshatton.org/SCSS_595.html)", in which he concludes that language choice is at least close to irrelevant and other factors (chiefly fluency in the chosen language) are the controlling factors.

About all I could add to that would be to summarize various other papers, in which defect rates for individual projects (and such) are given. I've done a bit of looking, and never found a correlation between language and defect rate, but that's not really the same as saying the defect rate is constant across languages (i.e., they *may* be different, but they vary so widely within each language that I've never been able to *prove* a difference).